# Get subarray by value of other subarray

Tags: javascript

I have next object:

```
u = {date:[1,2,2,1,5,6,2,8], uid:[11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88]}
```

And i want to get the array of values from 'uid' subarray by 'date' subarray.
Like this: give me uids where date is '1'.
Result: [11, 44].

How?

Comment: Its not clear what you're asking please elaborate!

Comment: Zip them, filter them, map to the output.

Comment: Lots of ways to get the results....including a simple `for` loop. Show what you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `map` (transforming each date element to its corresponding uid element if it matches your target date) and `filter` (to only keep "interesting" results in the final array):

```js
var u = {
  date: [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 8],
  uid: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
};

function getUid(date) {
  return u.date.map((d, i) => d === date ? u.uid[i] : false)
               .filter(v => v);
}

console.log(getUid(1));
console.log(getUid(5));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru the date array. Check if the value is the same with the date, `concat` the `u.uid[i]` to the accumulator.

```js
var u = {
  date: [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 8],
  uid: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88]
}

var date = 1;
var result = u.date.reduce((c, v, i) => v === date ? c.concat(u.uid[i]) : c, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the date array by taking the corresponding `uid` value at the same index if the date is the wanted date.

```js
function getUID(date) {
    return u.date.reduce(
        (r, d, i) => d === date
            ? r.concat(u.uid[i])
            : r,
        []
    );
}

var u = { date: [1, 2, 2, 1, 5, 6, 2, 8], uid: [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88] };

console.log(getUID(1));
```